# Powerbi calculate difference on two column values on Table

Tags: powerbi, difference

I have a Table visual on my dashboard:
 [image]

And i would like to calculate the difference between amount and amount2, and add an extra column to the table visual(use a measure?), it would look like this:

[image]

How to do this?

I hope you guys can help me out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you drag-and-dropped those amount columns onto your table, then Power BI automatically creates an *implicit measures* in the background that likely looks like `SUM(Table1[amount])` and `SUM(Table1[amount2])`. To calculate the difference, create a measure to subtract the second from the first:

```
Difference = SUM(Table1[amount]) - SUM(Table1[amount2])
```

There are other ways to write this as well. This might work too.

```
Difference = SUMX(Table1, Table1[amount] - Table1[amount2])
```

Comment: sorry forgot to say: amount and amount2 are from different tables, when I tried the first solution, its loading the data for like forever. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it would take significantly longer than calculating them separately.

Answer (score 1):

First, we have to create a relationship between tables

Then we have to create the many-one(*<->1) relation between those tables

[image]

We have to create a new column difference on today table

```
CDC Change = VALUE(RELATED(yesterdayDataBucketCount[KPI_Value])-  todayDataBucketCount[KPI_Value])
```

[image]